# Android: cannot create socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, libgdx

I'm having problems when creating a socket in android. I'm using LibGDX.

```
            @Override
public void create() {
    System.out.println("Enter IP adress.");
    ip = "78.61.65.198";

    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    socket = connection(PORT, ip);

    System.out.println("Setting up InputStream");
    reader = reader(socket);

    System.out.println("Setting up OutputStream");
    output = output(socket);

    while (socket.isConnected()) {
        output.println("0;" + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() + ";" + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY());
    }

}

public static Socket connection(int port, String ip) {
    try {
        return new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ip), port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unknown host...");
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to connect...");
        return null;
    }
}

public static BufferedReader reader(Socket socket) {

    try {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get inputStream...");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static PrintStream output(Socket socket) {
    try {
        return new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Couldn't get outputStream");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Server:

```
    @Override
public void create() {

    System.out.println("Creating server...");
    server = hostServer(PORT);

    System.out.println("Waiting for Client 1...");
    client1 = waitForConnections(server);

    System.out.println("Setting up input/output for client 1...");
    client1Input = reader(client1);
    client1Output = output(client1);

    setScreen(new gameScreen(this));

}


public static ServerSocket hostServer(int port){
    try {
        return new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Failed to host server!");
        return null;
    }
}

public static BufferedReader reader(Socket socket){
    try {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Failed to get input stream!");
        return null;
    }
}

public static PrintStream output(Socket socket){
    try {
        return new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Failed to create output stream!");
        return null;
    }
}

public static Socket waitForConnections(ServerSocket server){
    try {
        return server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Failed to accept connection!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works when i do it with a desktop project, but when i do it with an android project, it doesn't work.

ERROR: [image]

Let me know if anyone has similiar problems or have found a solution.

Comment: Your LogCat screenshot is a warning from an app that is not yours. Please explain, **in detail**, what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: It crashes with this exception. I have also added a USES-INTERNET permission in manifest file. Do i need more permissions?

Comment: "It crashes with this exception" -- again, that stack trace does not appear to be from your app.

Comment: How can you tell that?

Comment: Because it is referring to `com.samsung.aasaservice` and related Samsung things.

Comment: I updated the question. I have changed the screenshot.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. However, your client code says that it is connecting via `127.0.0.1`. Your stack trace shows your client code connecting via `78.61.65.198`. Those are not the same, suggesting that your client code does not match your stack trace. Also, in the future, please copy and paste the text of the stack trace for use in Stack Overflow questions, rather than difficult-to-read screenshots.

Comment: I have later changed 127.0.0.1 to my ip. the code in the question is outdated. i'll change that.

Comment: OK. Is your server listening on `78.61.65.198`? Or, is your server listening only on `127.0.0.1` (otherwise known as `localhost`)?

Comment: Are you sure your server is successfully listening on the port. Is it a activity or service that starts the server ?
did you see "Waiting for Client 1..." on console.

Comment: I presume it's on localhost, because i haven't specified the ip when creating a server (as you can see in the code).

Comment: I did see the message "waiting for client 1". It successfully communicates with a client that's created on desktop computer, however, it doesn't work on android. The problem is with the client, obviously.

Comment: Server activity/service needs to be started first before making any socket connection.

Comment: Server is started on my PC. Do i have to create intent service or anything like that on android to communicate with it?

Comment: Your code should works as you have explained.
put the code of connection(PORT, ip) method as well.

Comment: I have just updated the question. See the code again

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: @Martis Can you elaborate more about your setup? Is your computer and Android device both connected to the same LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both your PC and your Android device are connected to the same LAN (connected to the same router), you should try to use the server's **internal** IP address (usually looks like: 10.0.0.X or 192.168.X.X), which you can find by running the `ipconfig` command on the command line in a Windows PC, or `ifconfig` on Linux/MAC. If your PC and Android device are connected to different networks then you should use the server's **external** IP address like you did in your example. If it is the latter you should also forward the port your using (1234) to your PC in your router.

Answer (score 0):

When the server is startet on your pc, you cannot connect from another device than your pc as long as you try to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1. Only when running the app on your pc as desktop application the connection will work since client and server are on the same host. For other clients you need to connect to the local LAN IP address of your PC. When you try to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 from your phone it is looking for a server running on the phone and this is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

Is the client network connection estabished in an UI thread/activity? If so, network connection should established in a separate thread, eg. AsynTask for short operations and services for longer streaming operations. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask

Comment: That will not cause 'connection refused'.

Comment: right, thanks. It seems socket.isConnected() is called within an activity.